# Can't chroot to recover Ubuntu 64 bits

Tags: 64-bit, package-management, chroot, multiarch

I was trying to get steam for linux to work on my Ubuntu 10.04 LTS 64 bits system. I installed these three (some 32 bit) packages:

```
http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/libc-bin
http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/libc6
http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libc6-i386
```

And now my computer panics on boot.  I tried to chroot from an Ubuntu 10.04 Live CD using these commands:

```
mount /dev/sda1 /media/x
mount --bind /sys /media/x/sys
mount --bind /proc /media/x/proc
mount --bind /dev /media/x/dev
chroot /media/x
```

But I get this error:

```
chroot: cannot run command `/bin/bash': No such file or directory
```

But everything is there.  My entire system is on /media/x

I also tried using:

```
chroot /media/x /bin/bash
```

Please help!!

Comment: The `\`/bin/bash': No such file or directory` error can mean that some shared library was missing (or maybe the wrong bit-ness), even if `/bin/bash` itself exists. It's a confusing message.

Comment: you tried to chroot from where? i am confused, are you on a LiveCD and if yes, which one?

Comment: I am using lucid 10.04 lts.  And yes I tried to chroot from the live cd.

Comment: Oh and the live CD is the 64 bit edition!

Comment: @Dan: How did you install the 3 packages you linked at the top? If you did it manually, perhaps you overwrote the libc runtime with a 32-bit version. I think that would produce the `No such file` error.

Comment: I installed them via terminal using "force."

Comment: Would replacing bash with the 64-bit version from the live CD help?

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing something, and this is just a thought, but you are running Lucid, and installing packages for Quantal and Precise...and then you had kernel panic? Couldn't the problem be the mismatched packages having some incompatibility? The chroot failure would then be a secondary effect from the mismatch, even though they're both 64-bit.

Comment: According to the [Valve requirements](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux), Steam for Linux requires at least 12.04, fully updated. I'm not sure you can use these later packages with 10.04 to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

This will unfortunately not answer your question in any way, but it will hopefully increase your knowledge of how Ubuntu works *a lot*. No offence if you knew these things already. But if not, then I cannot let you not knowing those tips. The comments section is too small for this explanation.

### Installing a program

I have the impression that you downloaded the packages from http://packages.ubuntu.com and then installed them. Is that correct ? If yes, you have to know that downloading something from the web to install it is very common for Windows but very rare for Ubuntu.

Usually, you should use the Software Center or a command in the terminal containing "apt-get".

### Ubuntu versions names

The version number is for instance 10.04, 12.04 or 12.10. The first part indicates the year and the second indicates the month of release. For instance 12.04 came out in April 2012.

"LTS" means Long Term Support. There is an LTS version of Ubuntu every 2 years : 10.04 and 12.04 are the latest ones.

64bits and 32bits are related to your processor.

---

Have fun with Ubuntu and your video games ! I hope you'll get another answer that actually answers your question.

Comment: Epic fail answer.  Someone please help..